# At is scheduling the job but not executing the commands under it

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, operating-systems

Please help me solve my issue on at command.

I am giving the below command and it is not executing.

```
# at now
at> ls -l > txt.txt
at> <EOT>
job 1 at 2016-04-27 11:31
```

when I try to read txt.txt, there is no such file.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please format your question such that we can understand where _>_ identifies your command prompt and where it represents output redirection. You'll make the life of your voluntary supporters much easier.

Answer (score 0):

When using a scheduler, it is always a good idea to specify the full paths.

I suspect you're simply looking for the output in the wrong place or that you may not have write access to the output directory.

If you try the exact same command from outside `at`, does it work?  If not, please provide the permissions from the directory in question.

Comment: I presume your suspicion is inaccurate. If you take the time to consider `man at`, you'll find that e.g. the working directory and environment are preserved.